# Regex: non-zero number followed by one or more spaces followed by non-zero number

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to match a user input in the format [1-9], whitespace, [1-9]

So 

1 1 should pass

1 0 should fail

```
new Regex(@"^[1-9]+\s+\d+").IsMatch(input) //works but allows 0 for the 2nd number
new Regex(@"^[1-9]+\s+\[1-9]+").IsMatch(input) //does not work for some reason
```

I feel like I'm missing something super basic, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: The second one does not work because `\[` matches a literal `[`. Use `@"^[1-9]\s[1-9]$"` if `1 12` is invalid and only valid inputs are 2 single digit numbers with a single whitespace between them. If the numbers just can't start with a `0`, use [`@"^[1-9][0-9]*\s+[1-9][0-9]*$"`](https://regex101.com/r/ZRMB2q/1)

Comment: You can try [`^(?!0)\d+\s+(?!0)\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/TXEgv5/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your regexps do not work as intended. The `^[1-9]+\s+\d+` pattern matches 1+ digits from `1` to `9`, then 1+ whitespaces, and then any 1+ digits that can be followed with anything, any number of any chars. The `^[1-9]+\s+\[1-9]+` pattern contains an escaped `[` and instead of matching any 1+ digits from `1` to `9` with `[1-9]` your `\[1-9]+` matches a `[`, then `1-9` substring and then 1+ `]` chars.

If you plan to match strings consisting of single non-zero digits separated with 1+ whitespaces, use `@"^[1-9]\s+[1-9]$"`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CUHBRR/2).

If you plan to match a string that consists of two digit chunks not starting with `0` and separated with 1 or more whitespace chars, use

```
@"^[1-9][0-9]*\s+[1-9][0-9]*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRMB2q/1). Note that `$` is an end of string anchor that does not allow almost any chars after it (it does allow an `\n` at the end of the string, so, you might want to use `\z` instead of `$`).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[1-9]` - a `1`, `2`... `9`
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digtis
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `[1-9][0-9]*` - see above
- `$` / `\z` - end of string / the very end of string anchors.